# How to ensure an upper limit of service calls when client code runs on a number of machines?

Tags: java, rest, service, distributed-computing, throttling

Suppose I have a restful service X with an API getName(String id). My code is deployed to 5 machines which are behind a load balancer. Same client code runs on these machines and somewhere it makes a call to service X for getName(String) api. The service has put a restriction that it will handle maximum of 3 calls per second. Suppose the turn around time for a request is 200 ms, how do I ensure that my clients don't surpass the 3 TPS limit of the server? I have no mechanism for my clients to communicate with each other. How do I avoid the throttling on server side. What if I grow my fleet size to 10 or 15 from 5? Is there some thing that I can do?

Would something like a truncated exponential backoff work for me?

Comment: exponential backoff is really for the cases where the client is re-trying to hit your service....and to prevent to frequent retries overwhelming your service...in your case you need to disallow more than calls per second totally right....not entertain more than 3 calls per second from any ip ??

Comment: I take care of the client side. How am I going to ensure I don't make more than 3 calls per second is my question, why are u asking it back lol. I don't know how to ensure that, thats what I am asking

Comment: What happens if you make more than 3 calls per second?  Do you get an error that identifies the issue, and can you retry the request later?  Does the failed request count toward the 3 calls per second?

Comment: Yes The request is throlled/dropped at the server side and I as a client get an exception. Currently on my client side I have a simple try-catch where in catch i retry the call again using exponential backoff strategy. Not sure if this is the only/right approach

Answer (score 0):

You just have to save the **request arrival times** of last 3 requests in the session. Then check if the 4th request is within that 1 second window or not.

Assuming t0 is the 4th request in this timeline (Time in milliseconds),

...--t3-----t2-----t1----t0----

```
if ((t0 - 1000) > t3) {
    //4th req within 1 sec, so process the request
} else {
    //return HTTP status code 502(service temporarily overloaded)
}
```

*If you want to throttle across the load balancer:* One solution would be to use some API/storage common to all the API instances.